# Verify if google event already exist before creating it

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I used the google documentation to be able to add a google calendar event using python coding.

But what i want, is to be able to verify if X date time slot is empty before able to add the event.

here is my code :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

event_summary = 'test123'
event_location = 'h4n1p9'
event_start = '2020-04-22T05:00:00-00:00'
event_end = '2020-04-22T08:00:00-00:00'

new_event = {
    'summary': event_summary,
    'location': event_location,
    'description': '',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': event_start,
        'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': event_end,
        'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
     },
    'reminders': {
                'useDefault': True,
    },

}

class PostToGoogleCalendar:

    def __init__(self):
        self.creds = None
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                self.creds = pickle.load(token)
        if not self.creds or not self.creds.valid:
            if self.creds and self.creds.expired and self.creds.refresh_token:
                self.creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                self.creds = flow.run_local_server()
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(self.creds, token)

        self.service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)

    def get_events(self):
        now = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        events_result = self.service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                                   maxResults=500, singleEvents=True,
                                                   orderBy='startTime').execute()
        return events_result.get('items', [])

    def create_event(self, new_event):
        if not self.already_exists(new_event):
            event = self.service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=new_event).execute()
            return event.get('htmlLink')
        else:
            return 'Event Already Exists'

    def already_exists(self, new_event):
        events = self.get_date_events(new_event['start']['dateTime'], self.get_events())
        event_list = [new_event['summary'] for new_event in events]
        if new_event['summary'] not in event_list:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def get_date_events(self, date, events):
        lst = []
        date = date
        for event in events:
            if event.get('start').get('dateTime'):
                d1 = event['start']['dateTime']
                if d1 == date:
                    lst.append(event)
        return lst
```

This code is suppose to verify the events in 2020-04-22. IF theres an event at the chosen time, returns me that event is found, if not, create the event in calendar.

But it's not working, i get no error, but nothing happens neither..

Comment: You are not getting anything on the console because you are just returning from the functions. To figure out what is going on better, could you please ```print``` the ```event_list``` on the function ```already_exists``` to see what you are get in there and let me know how that goes? Also, is the event you are testing this with already there? Is anything changing on your calendar? Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Hey! Thanks for your comment. I tried printing the `event_list` on the function `already_exists`. But i dont get anything!!!!  nothing is changing to my calendar... i tested if event is already there and if it's empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

It adds the event if time slot is free, or else display the registered event if no free.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 1 event on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    event_summary = 'Test_Cal'
    event_location = 'h4n1p9'
    event_description = 'test'
    event_start = '2020-04-29T19:00:00-00:00'
    event_end = '2020-04-29T20:00:00-00:00'

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Looking if already created - if not, will create')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=event_start,
                                          maxResults=1, singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:

        event = {
            'summary': event_summary,
            'location': event_location,
            'description': '',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': event_start,
                'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': event_end,
                'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
            },
            'reminders': {
                'useDefault': True,
            },

        }

        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

        print('new event created')

    for event in events:
        print('Cannot create new event because time slot already taken by : ')
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'], event['location'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Feel free to comment if existing code can be modified.